# TestCafe With Electron: can't load main page (main page may return a '304' http code)

Tags: testing, automated-tests, electron, e2e-testing, testcafe

When my electron-app starts, it will do some initial action like 'checking config or checking status', after initial done it will redirect to a new path. I think the `http 304 status-code` causes this error:

> Error: The main window page at file:///E:/code/electron_ct/public/app.html was not loaded.
>   Use the mainWindowUrl option to specify one of the following pages as the main window page: file:///E:/code/electron_ct/public/app.html#/signin

I'd appreciate it if you can give me any advice.

Answer (score 2):

TestCafe expects that the `mainWindowUrl` property that you set in your `.testcafe-electron-rc` file will have an exact match with a URL that your Electron app loads when starting up. Anchors (like `#signin`) are required to be the same too.

The error message highlights that your app tries to open `file:///E:/code/electron_ct/public/app.html` while `mainWindowUrl` is configured to `file:///E:/code/electron_ct/public/app.html#/signin`. You should append `/#signin` to the `mainWindowUrl`'s value.